# #ifdef WIN32 #elif WIN64 #endif

Tags: c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have come across [some example code](http://bojan-komazec.blogspot.de/2011/10/conditional-compilation-of-resource.html) that goes like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
   ...
#elif WIN64
   ...
#endif
```

In an `#ifdef` block, is it actually legal to use `#elif` to mean `#elif defined`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be.  That's not to say that some obscure C compiler wouldn't accept it as such, but it isn't part of the C standard.

Normally, for something like this you would use either `#elifdef FOO` (which I've never actually seen in production code) or `#elif defined(FOO)` (like you mentioned).

This code appears to be working in a odd way; it's rather first checking if `WIN32` is defined, then checking if `WIN64` is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. (It seems, hoewever, that the Visual Studio resource editor doesn't like either workaround, and simply needs `#elif` without argument).

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps Visual Studio's .rc files just have their own (completely different) syntax.

Comment: Assuming that `WINxx` is defined as 1, this code isn't strictly wrong, just weird (prob. not what they intended). Remember undefined names expand to 0 in expressions, so this is ill-typed, but valid logic.

Comment: That's a good point, but that assumes `#define WINxx 1`, not `#define WINxx`.

Comment: @Leushenko This assumption cannot be met, because afaik you can just define setting-dependent symbols in the project settings, but not give the symbols any specific value.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: the snippet above by itself is not strictly invalid, just inconsistent, because the constants *could* be defined as 1, and in that specific situation it would work. While a bad idea, it's possible that this is still what the original author assumed. (It's also possible that the constants are documented to be defined as 1 or not at all, in which case this is a bad idea with corporate approval.)